# Django project doesn't 'see' Python modules installed with Pipenv

Tags: python, django, pipenv

I am just starting out with Django and I have this problem. The files are written in the Pipfile, for future reference, but my Django project cannot make use of the actual modules. I have to go to the folder where pipenv install them: C:\Users\my_name.virtualenvs\my_folder and I usually copy them from there and paste them in my working folder. That kind of defeats the purpose, and its not very convinient. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to double check, are you selecting the proper Python interpreter?

You can double check by clicking where the arrow points, and picking the one with the parentheses, as displayed in the screenshot.

[image]